# How to use Bootstrap to create a responsive menu similar to Facebook mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css, facebook, twitter-bootstrap

How do I go about creating a Mobile Menu button that is pretty much exactly like Facebook mobile? I have Bootstrap 3 setup and a responsive menu for the mobile section. The only issue is the menu drops from the top instead of coming in from the left side. Does Bootstrap have a built in option for this?

Here is what I have so far in the body:

```
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="navbar-brand">Brand</div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Page 4</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Is this something that can be done with Bootstrap or does it take a different plugin working with Bootstrap? If so, which plugin?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a jQuery plugin, http://www.berriart.com/sidr/. It's responsive, open source, facebook menu implemented, well documented.

Comment: How do I go about integrating Sidr with the existing Bootstrap code? They don't seem to want to play nicely together.

Comment: Sidr already got two stylesheets. You can edit it with your requirement. If I understood you, you wanna create left/right sidebar navigation, right? To do that you won't need to add anything from bootstrap to Sidr's css. Just play with Sidr's stylesheet as your requirements.

Comment: But the responsive setup for Sidr is completely different than the responsive setup for Bootstrap. There has to be a blend of the two somewhere in the Body code.

Comment: What are you upto? Are you trying to implement a sidebar menu or toggle collapse from header menu? You know, facebook mobile is just like sidr on windows phone.

Comment: It's a bit of both. I'm trying to setup the site so that it's got the nav bar from bootstrap when in desktop mode. Then when the window is made smaller like in mobile mode the menu button with the three lines appears. Then the user can click and button and the menu slides in from left to right. The Sidr site is using exactly what I'm looking for just a different button in the upper left when the window is smaller.

Comment: All right. You will probably need to create two navigation menu for that. One for wide devices and another for small devices. You can use responsive utils as documented on http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities. In your wide device nav menu, for example in `<nav class="navbar">` add this `visible-md` after `navbar` `<nav class="navbar visible-md">`. Adding this will only visible on wider than 992px devices. Accordingly use `visible-xs` for sidr.

Comment: Is that what you need?

Comment: Doesn't bootstrap create two navigation menus already? I mean at the start all the options are up at the top within the navbar and then once the screen shrinks to a certain size it switches and puts everything within the button. Would this be easier with screenshots?

Comment: Yes it does. You can follow this tutorial http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-twitter-bootstrap-3/. But I like to create custom navigations for my requirements. Like right now on which project I'm working, it have three different navigation styles.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can use sidr plugin as answered by Swagata...

you can refer below post which explains same.

[Create a responsive menu similar to facebook mobile with Bootstrap using Sidr plugin](http://www.iminfo.in/post/create-responsive-menu-similar-to-facebook-mobile-with-bootstrap-using-sidr-plugin)